# MKPinAnnotationView: Animate pin color change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mkmapview

I want to make some pins stand out from the rest by animating their pin color. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: subclass the annotation view.

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324744/ipad-mapkit-change-title-of-current-location) a simple example.