# iOS / MKMapView: If one assigns to the image property of an MKAnnotationView an animated UIImage, it is not animated

Tags: ios, animation, uiimage, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have an `MKMapView` to which I add `MKAnnotations`. When they are displayed on the map, they use an `MKAnnotationView` with an `(UIImage *)image` property for custom annotation views.
If I now create an animated `UIImage` with the `+(UIImage *)animatedImageNamed:(NSString *)name duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` method and assign it to the `image` property of the `MKAnnotationView`, the displayed annotation view is **not** animated.
I cannot find anything in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that forbids to assign an animated `UIImage` to this `image` property, nor that it does no animation.
Sorry, there is not much code to show: Just setup the annotation view, and assign to its `image` property an animated image:
`MKAnnotationView *customAnnotationView` is allocated and initialized with `initWithAnnotation:reuseIdentifier:`
Then `customAnnotationView.image = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:name duration:duration];`

Is there anything I missed or just a missing hint in the docs or do I something wrong?

Comment: Seems to be a limitation of the MKAnnotationView.  Unless you can find an easier solution, you could create a custom annotation view that does the animation manually.  The answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324744/ipad-mapkit-change-title-of-current-location) gives an example of something similar (it "animates" pin color instead of the image though).

Comment: @Anna Karenina: Thanks for your hint, but I have implemented the animation in code earlier when I was not yet aware of the animated UIImages. I now thought it would be so much easier just to take a standard animated image, but this seems not to be possible.

Comment: I just submitted a bug report to Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a friend gave me a tip for a workaround:
Make a `UIImageView` of the animated image, and embed it as a subview into another not-animated container `UIView`, and use this not-animated container view as the image of the `MKAnnotationView`.
In this case, the annotation view shows the animated image.